# Send wav files through socket

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, wav, wave

I am trying to send a wav file through a socket.

I get the error:

```
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not instance
```

---

```
waveFile = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'rb')
my_socket.sendall(waveFile)
```

Comment: the code i wrote above, my_socket.send(),wavefile=open(...).read()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `wave` doesn't give you general file I/O. It is used for getting media properties.

You could use just normal open/close, read/write.

**sender.py:**

```
import socket

(HOST,PORT)=('localhost',19123)
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM); s.connect((HOST,PORT))

with open('input', 'rb') as f:
  for l in f: s.sendall(l)
s.close()
```

**receiver.py:**

```
import socket

(HOST,PORT) = ('localhost',19123)
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT)); s.listen(1); conn, addr = s.accept()

with open('output','wb') as f:
  while True:
    l = conn.recv(1024)
    if not l: break
    f.write(l)
s.close()
```

Comment: clients code:
'while data:
    alldata+=data
    data=client_socket.recv(1024)
voice=open("voice.p",'wb')
voice.write(alldata)'
raises me the error-wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id

Comment: I changed `send` to `sendall`. The former is not guaranteed to send all bytes (and needs to be retried with remaining bytes). The latter sends all bytes. It doesn't need retries.

Comment: On the client side, don't do string operations, like `alldata+=data;`. I don't think they are safe on byte arrays.

Comment: so what should i do on the client side?

Comment: @user4719989, added code for a complete sender and receiver combination.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`socket.sendfile(file, offset=0, count=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendfile).

> Send a file until EOF is reached by using high-performance [`os.sendfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.sendfile) …

And you don't want to open the file with `wave.open(...)` as you are sending raw binary data.

So you would do:

```
with open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'rb') as wave_file:
    my_socket.sendfile(wave_file)
```

Comment: it is raising me the error error-AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'sendfile'

Comment: i am using windows ir its matter

Comment: socket.sendfile() doesn't exit in Python 2.7.